# Passing unions via generics on conditional types assigns any instead of the union

Tags: typescript

I need a generic type to assign to my actions. Actions can be either functions or functions that return a function, like this:

```
() => void
() => (input: I) => void
```

I have created an Action type with a conditional generic Input, like this:

```
type ConditionalInput<I = null> = I extends null
    ? () => void
    : () => (input: I) => void;
```

It works great when you don't pass an Input:

```
const action1: ConditionalInput = () => { } // Fine;
```

And when you pass an Input that is not a union:

```
const action2: ConditionalInput<string> = () => str => { } // Fine;
```

but the input is `any` when you pass a union:

```
const action3: ConditionalInput<string | number> =
    () => strOrNum => { } // str is any!!;
```

This is a playground with the code: [TS Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20ConditionalInput%3CI%20%3D%20null%3E%20%3D%20I%20extends%20null%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3F%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20(input%3A%20I)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20action1%3A%20ConditionalInput%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20Fine%3B%0D%0Aconst%20action2%3A%20ConditionalInput%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20str%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20Fine%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20action3%3A%20ConditionalInput%3Cstring%20%7C%20number%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20()%20%3D%3E%20strOrNum%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20str%20is%20any!!%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20NonConditionalInput%3CI%3E%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20(input%3A%20I)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20action4%3A%20NonConditionalInput%3Cstring%20%7C%20number%3E%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20()%20%3D%3E%20strOrNum%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20Fine%3B)

By the way, the union works fine if I don't use conditionals:

```
type NonConditionalInput<I> = () => (input: I) => void;

const action4: NonConditionalInput<string | number> =
    () => strOrNum => { } // Fine;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have hit upon the [distributive behavior](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) of conditional types. Basically the conditional type is applied to each member of the union and the result is the union of all applications. So in your case,  `ConditionalInput<string | number> == ((input: string) => void) | ((input: number) => void);`

To disable distribution, use a tuple :

```
type ConditionalInput<I = null> = [I] extends [null]
    ? () => void
    : () => (input: I) => void;


const action3: ConditionalInput<string | number> =
    () => strOrNum => { } // ok now
```

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't know about that :)